# Meaning of "Wer wird eingeweiht"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Das größte Risiko sind dabei nicht die Bomben, sondern gezielte Entführungen durch die Terroristen des "Islamischen Staates" oder durch andere Kriminelle. Diese Gefahr macht jede Reise ins Kampfgebiet zu einer Expedition, die man über Wochen planen muss: Welche Gruppen operieren wo? Wer wird **eingeweiht**, wer unbedingt gemieden?

According to the dictionary, [einweihen](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/einweihen) means to open/christen/initiate. But it doesn't seem to fit in this context well. What does "Wer wird eingeweiht" mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Wer wird eingeweiht" means "who do you tell about your travel plans"?

"Einweihen" can either refer to some kind of opening or to some secret. In the latter case, there are a couple of opportunities [according to PONS](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/einweihen):

- if the secret is some kind of cult or rite: to initiate
- if it is a secret of your own, some private thing: to tell somebody about, to let somebody in on, to divulge
- if it is a plan: to outline, to unveil, to present

For the given example I would opt for "who would you let in on it" or simply "who would you tell about it" - but I am not an English native.

Answer (score 6):

When there is a group which shares a secret and they want to include another person by telling her their secret you would *"jemanden (in etwas) einweihen"*.

The closest English translation I found is **to bring somebody into the loop**.